# zend square brackets in form element name

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-form

I have one problem with Zend Framework. I included into my form MultiCheckbox element and it adds square brackets to it's name in HTML(for example I need element with name tags, but ZF makes it tags[]).

When I use this form in my home development server everything just works fine. But then I uploaded code to production server it just went wrong. When putting to database I have to make column named tags[] and because php uses square brackets for arrays everything crashes and I can't use it in my view.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square braquets is the normal way to define an array for data used with `$_GET` and `$_POST` methods.

In your PHP script, you need to unserialize the array and parse or do what you want with your array.

```
<?php 
    //Example for $_REQUEST["item"] = "item[]=1&item[]=2"

    $arr = unserialize($_REQUEST["item"]); 
    foreach($arr as $index => $position)
    {
        //Do what you want
    }
?>
```